# Extent of Thread Safety in R/ Rcpp

Tags: r, multithreading, thread-safety, openmp, rcpp

I know that R, and by extension Rcpp, are generally not thread-safe. This script e.g. crashes R:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List example_fun(const int list_length) {
  Rcpp::List example_list (list_length);

  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
  for(int i = 0; i < list_length; ++i) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector example_vector = something();
    example_list[i] = example_vector;
  }
  return example_list;
}
```

[Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support) states "Calling any of the R API from threaded code is ‘for experts only’ and strongly discouraged". That is vague, but says that multithreading is technically possible (I suppose it includes multiprocessing). With this question, I want to find out what the "experts only" use cases are, in which Rcpp objects can be used in parallelized code.

1. I can test code on my machines and check, if it throws an error. But that does not tell me whether the approach is generally thread-safe. It might work fine with the example I wrote or the infrastructure I am running it on, but could fail in other applications and on other machines. What e.g. works fine on my machines is replacing elements of a preallocated vector:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector example_fun(const int vector_length) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector example_vector (vector_length);

  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
  for(int i = 0; i < vector_length; ++i) {
    example_vector[i] = something();
  }
  return example_vector;
}
```

The data I pass to and from R is quite large in my application. Tests showed the overhead of copying the data to or from std::vector to be huge. And, of course, it also notably increases RAM use. I suppose it is pretty much the same with RcppParallel::RVector and arma::vec. Running the code serially is not an option either, as that would extend the execution time by days.

2. I am wondering whether the `critical` option could ensure thread safety. It restricts a code region not be executed by more than one thread at a time. In the loop above, this might translate to:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
for(int i = 0; i < vector_length; ++i) {
  const double element_i = something();
  #pragma omp critical(vectorupdate)
  {
    example_vector[i] = element_i;
  }
}
```

3. Does thread safety concern local loop variables? In

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
for(int i = 0; i < outer_vector_length; ++i) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector example_vector (inner_vector_length);
  for(int j = 0; j < inner_vector_length; ++j) {
    example_vector[j] = something();
  }
}
```

`example_vector` is always accessed by the same thread.

4. To what extent are read-only objects passed from R thread-safe?

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>

double something(const int i, const Rcpp::NumericVector& in_vector) {
  ...
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector example_fun(const Rcpp::NumericVector& in_vector, const int out_vector_length) {
  std::vector<double> out_vector (out_vector_length);

  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
  for(int i = 0; i < vector_length; ++i) {
    out_vector[i] = something(i, in_vector);
  }
  return Rcpp:wrap(out_vector);
}
```

Since `in_vector` is not modified at all in C++, it should be safe to call in a parallel loop, right? I know that there is no need to use `const` and `&` with Rcpp objects, since Rcpp does not enforce const correctness and objects are always passed by reference. I simply added them to the syntax here to underline my point.

5. What about using an Rcpp vector as a loop variable? Is that thread-safe?

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector example_fun(Rcpp::IntegerVector& in_vector) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector out_vector (in_vector.size());

  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
  for(const int & i : in_vector) {
    out_vector[i] = something();
  }
  return example_vector;
}
```

I really want to learn about the "expert only" fashion in which R objects can be used in parallel OpenMP C++ code. I am not able to extract the information myself from R's source code. So I am counting on someone here clarifying this issue for me (maybe an R core developer)?

### Edit

Following Dirk Eddelbuettel's quote in the comments below ("Any memory that may be subject to a `gc()` operation by R cannot be accessed"), I did some further reading. In particular, I read http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html, https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html, ?Memory, ?gc, https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Profiling-R-code-for-memory-use, and https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#SEXPs. Unfortunately, these sources taught me very little that I did not already know on the topic. Hadley Wickham e.g. writes in https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html: "The garbage collector (GC) runs automatically whenever R needs more memory to create a new object". Given that, I still do not understand why approach 4 (with this edit, I added number to question components) is not thread-safe? In it, I pass the reference to an R vector and read elements from it in a parallel loop. From the start of the function until the end of the loop, I do not add, update, or remove any R object. I write elements to a C++ std::vector. So, why should R alter any of its objects or invalidate the pointer?

Neither have I figured out, why the mutex (`#pragma omp critical`) does not make the code thread-safe.

What also puzzles me, is why approach 1 is not thread-safe. Updating a vector element in R (`example_vector[i] <- 5`) modifies it in place, if no other object is pointing to that data. No data is copied and the pointer remains valid. Why is it a problem to do it in parallel in C++?

Sorry for annoying the participants of this discussion. I really want to learn how this works.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that if there was an easy answer that would fit the format of SO Q&A, it would probably be given instead of the "for experts only".

Comment: Maybe the answer is easy. It appears to just not be documented. An R core developer should be able to answer my questions with a few lines of text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070245/14778592

Comment: May I invite to search among the 3000 questions under the `[rcpp]`  tag as this has all been discussed before.  A general recommendation is to study the vignette of package `RcppParallel` as it patiently discusses many key aspects.

Comment: I am asking here because I did not find answers to my questions in any other SO post, the RcppParallel, or any other site. SO answers repeat like a mantra to use other data structures like RcppParallel::RVector, std::vector etc. That is a simple suggestion, but not what I am after. I want to explicity know in which cases I can use OpenMP with R's native data structures.

Comment: There is a frequently repeated line (and I am fairly sure I lift it from the RcppParallel docs):  "Any memory that may be subject to a `gc()` operation by R cannot be accessed."  No mutex or other control can help you there.  And trouble is _may_.  Things _may_ work on one machine, or setup.  But they might fail in another instance.

Comment: I think you should consider deleting the post, and maybe asking on r-devel.  You are _fundamentally_ asking the wrong question in the wrong place (in the sense that Rcpp does little here). Eg everything that goes in and out of R is a `SEXP` and the P is always a pointer so you simply cannot fully seal an object to get immutability.  Which, connected with the `gc()` rule, means you cannot touch anything that came from R in an OpenMP / pthread context of threading.   None of what I just said is specific to Rcpp so why write a 1000 words expose here were only Rcpp specialists will see it?

Comment: The question has five tags, incl. the general `r` tag. So, it is not just Rcpp specialists seeing it. I am considering adding a bounty to it, so that it receives more attention throughout the R community. But I will also consider asking on r-devel. Since Rcpp wraps `SEXP`, it think it is not unreasonable to add the `rcpp` tag. I did not know to what extent Rcpp wrapping the C API affects the topics I am investigating.

Comment: I edited the title to point out that it targets R more broadly.

Comment: I suggest you remove Rcpp from the Subject and the tags. Rcpp is simply the conduit here but it does not (as it cannot (!!)) change anything about R can, or cannot, use threading.